# applying a list-style-image to the given ul only, not to subjacent ul's

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a `<ul id="islist">` with the according css:

```
#islist {
    list-style-image: url('../img/img.png');
}

#islist * li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Then, within this , there's another one:

```
<ul id="islist">
    <li>title</li>
    <ul>
        <li>li1</li>
        <li>li2</li>
        <li>li3</li>
        <li>li4</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

The problem is that all `<li>` elements have the image setup, not only the `title`.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html is invalid you cant have a ul as a child of a ul, place the ul in an li and then the styles will be applied to the nested lis.

```
<ul id="islist">
    <li>title</li>
    <li><ul>
        <li>li1</li>
        <li>li2</li>
        <li>li3</li>
        <li>li4</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

also I think you want to use `list-style: none;` instead of `list-style-type:none;`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/9pAsk/)

Comment: Wrong. You can nest a `<ul>` within another one. That is how submenus are formatted.

Comment: `list-style: none;` was the problem

Comment: My bad. I misinterpreted as "No `<ul>` should be in any `<ul>`". Yes, for submenus `<ul>` should and should only be embedded in `<li>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the style is applied to the `ul`, not to the `li`.
Change the CSS as follows:

```
#islist {
    list-style-image: url('../img/img.png');
}

#islist ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```